# Read systemd WatchdogSec from EnvironmentFile

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to read systemd WatchdogSec configuration from environment variable set in EnvironmentFile? Like

```
WatchdogSec=$MY_WD_TIMEOUT
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

systemd is quite specific about which configuration directives will expand variables (which are for the most part the `Exec` ones, such as `ExecStart=`) and `WatchdogSec=` is not one of them.

If the reason you're looking into this is to allow specifying a custom watchdog timeout that is independent of the shipped unit file, or that can be customized without modifying the unit file, then the recommended feature to accomplish that is to use override files.

For example, you can have a `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service.d/watchdog_timeout.conf` with the two lines below:

```
[Service]
WatchdogSec=30s
```

This will override any default settings from `myapp.service`, even if that unit is shipped in `/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service` and not `/etc`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The reason I'm asking is that I'm trying to define a common watchdog timeout length to be used for a group of processes.

Comment: You still need to set it for each individual unit. If you use override files, you can use symlinks to have them all point to the same file. (In which case, you can update it in a single place.)